# nodejs require inside a object literal and using it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

using require like this below , can it cause any issues ?

```
module.exports = {
    _                   : require('lodash'),
    debug               : require('debug'),
    moment              : require('moment'),
    jwt                 : require('jsonwebtoken'),
    bcrypt              : require('bcrypt'),
    SwaggerExpress      : require('swagger-express-mw'),
    express             : require('express'),
    Sequelize           : require('sequelize'),
    SequelizeImport     : require('sequelize-auto-import'),
    twilio              : require('twilio'),
    DataTransform       : require("node-json-transform").DataTransform,
    joi                 : require('joi'),
    joiDateExtension    : require('joi-date-extensions'),
    joiPhoneExtension   : require('joi-phone-number-extensions'),
    requireAll          : require('require-all'),
    leftPad             : require('left-pad'),
    cors                : require('cors'),
    sendgrid            : require('@sendgrid/mail'),
    randomstring        : require('randomstring'),
    withPagination      : require('sequelize-cursor-pagination'),
    razorpay            : require('razorpay'),
    axios               : require('axios'),
    SlackNode           : require('slack-node'),
    emojiStrip          : require('emoji-strip'),
    firebase            : admin,
    apn                 : apn,
    apnProvider         : apnProvider
    // aws                 : AWS,
    // multer              : require('multer')
};
```

m assigning it to express instance and using it.

```
const moment        = App.packages.moment;
const firebase      = App.packages.firebase;
const _             = App.packages._;
const emojiStrip    = App.packages.emojiSt
```

Comment: what is your use case?

Comment: There is no problem maintaining libraries in another file. This is known as separate of concerns SOC.

Comment: nodejs api server, i just wanted to organize the require through out the , so that all require is at one place n other member of the team can use packages easily

Comment: i am facing memory leak in the nodejs server i made, so trying to questing every thing i did so far

Comment: what's wrong with requiring packages normally? `const moment        = App.packages.moment;` is even longer than `const moment        = require("moment");`

Comment: @marzelin jst wanted to organize, anyone on the team require any package, should require here especially those packages which r being used in lots of files, and also i was trying to make small micro framework,

Answer (score -1):

This is formally uncorrect.

See Express docs:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

You can of course experiment different things but you need to know the risk. Always try to stick to common standards.

There is no problem in multiple requiring of packages in different files as they are just pulled from the `node_modules` folder, you are not creating multiple instances.

Answer (score -2):

Any how module is loaded once. so I don't think it will cause an issue.